# Strange behaviour, loadByAttribute() works in local but not on production server

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, model

I have been pulling my hair on this for a couple of hours now. I have a local development server that is quite the copy of my Magento production store. I have been working locally for the past few years with no problems. I noticed today I cannot load a product by attribute on the production server but it works locally.

An example:

```
$productModel   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product        = $productModel->loadByAttribute('sku', 'MYSKU');
```

This works locally, but not in production. I get a:

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function getData() on a non-object
```

The only changes we did lately is adding a new store in our Magento. But locally too I have 2 stores and it works. Why the object is not instantiated when loading by attribute?

Any idea where the issue could be?

Comment: Is the 'flat catalog product' feature enabled in production ?
I ask you because i had one day the same issue : flat product was enable and I had to set the sku attribute to be "used_in_product_listing" (doing this sku will be in the flat tables once reindexed and you can use again loadByAttributes('sku', value) method)

Comment: Oui Julien, I use the flat catalog, but I have "used_in_product_listing" set to No. But on the dev setup I have it at No too and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I am so confused. It was my mistake and I cannot believe it took me so long to figure it out...

I stupidly did all my tests using the SKU "1HC220/HEART", so filtering it in the Magento grid I got the product "1HC220/HEART**2**", I didn't see the extra "2". So it was findable loading it by ID, but by SKU as "1HC220/HEART" doesn't exist, it was failing.

It was so strange that suddenly such a basic thing stopped working.

Sorry for wasting your time guys.

Answer (score 1):

Actually what I can assume here is the product which you are trying to access is not there on production.
Try loading it directly once by using

```
$productId = <your product id>;
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

And if you are loading it via sku, check whether you are getting your product or not. You can also try this too.

```
$product = $productModel->loadByAttribute('sku', 'MYSKU');
foreach($product as $prod )
print_r($prod->getData());
```

Comment: the product data load correctly by ID, so your first suggestion works. It is using `loadByAttribute()` that _stopped_ working. Hence your second example throws the error.

Comment: $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getIdBySku('your sku');
if ($id) {
    $product->load($id);
}

Try this

Comment: I tried this too, same error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object`. Believe me I tried all ways to get a product's data by an attribute (sku in my case). I really wonder what is going wrong...

Comment: I think your product is not saved correctly. Try re-saving it and perform indexing. Also check if you have flat table enabled on both server or not. I mean both having same configurations?0

Comment: Yes both setups are the same and I have been working on them for years now without a problem. The product I take for my tests is an old one, so it has been there for quite some time, re-saving doesn't change much. Neither re-indexing. But thanks for your time @Vivek